# Thorax.js installation error (bower)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I just followed this guide: https://github.com/walmartlabs/thorax-seed/blob/master/README.md and encountered a strange issue on a windows maschine. When i run

```
npm start
```

there is a lot of work done by bower (it loads the dependencies I guess), but in the end I get some strange errors:

Command line output: http://pastebin.com/6exW5RGT

Contents of npm-debug: http://pastebin.com/bUmgKM8t

bower.json contents: http://pastebin.com/Vf1ffMDa

I don't know where to ask for help (I guess it's also windows specific, as I wasn't able to google this error), so I try it here.

Answer (score 0):

In the meanwhile, there is a Yeoman based generator for Thorax that might help you: https://github.com/walmartlabs/generator-thorax

Also, I am trying to setup a Google group to improve discussions on Thorax: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!forum/thoraxjs